Macbook 12in Early 2005 does not Recognize hard Drive
I have a MacBook 12in Early 2005 that when I try to boot up shows the folder with an interrogation mark symbol. I tried yo boot in recovery and the hard drive does not show up in the Disk Manager. What might be the issue?

There are problems with this question. Apple did not make any MacBooks in 2005. Any Macs built in 2005 cannot boot to Recovery, because all versions of OS X compatible with 2005 Macs do not have a Recovery partition to boot to. Instead, you booted from an installation DVD.

The only 12" MacBooks are from 2015 through 2017. For these MacBooks, the drive is soldered and cannot be replaced. Apple did not make any 12" MacBook Air or MacBook Pro models.

The internal HD is dead. Seeing that the Mac is almost 20 years old, this is most certainly the problem. Spinning disks have a finite lifetime. You don’t mention if you have been using this Mac since 2005, or if it has been unused for some length of time.
